# Best HTTP method for a stateless REST API service call

Tags: api, rest, http, methods

I want to make a REST API that does spellchecking on text that is passed in, without storing any of the text on the server.

The call would probably look something like `example.com/api/v1/spelling/mistakes', with optional query param for locale and an list of the mistakes as return value.

What would be the best HTTP method to use, given that the text passed in would be too large for a GET. Neither POST, PUT nor PATCH seem to reasonably map to the intended purpose and there don't seem to be any other suitable matches in the less commonly used methods either.

What is the best HTTP method to use for a "translation"-like REST API service, taking and returning large amounts of data?

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is a POST.  But it could have been a GET if the data was previously posted.  The reason it is not a GET is because you are passing all the data in this API call, as you mentioned.  For example, if the data was 'posted' somewhere else previously, then the GET can be used where the address (URI)  of the location, or ID, of that 'posted' data is passed to the API as a param in the GET.  But because we are both 'posting' the data and retrieving information about that in the same call, I would say then that this is a POST.  Grant it the data being posted has a short life span, it is still being posted.  If the data being posted was instead a customer order, then it would still be a POST but the data would be persisted somewhere.  The difference here is the the short period of time that the data will exist for.  And in future iterations of your API, you might actually want to keep that data and refer back to it with some ID.  So by using POST you allow for future enhancements also.

By the way, as a precaution, be careful with the memory footprint of these calls.  I can see this as being very memory intensive if the data being passed grows large and the API becomes very popular.  Not a show stopped but something to consider when designing it.

Hope that helps alleviate what I call REST anxiety when designing an API.